# sp2013: How to change/setup http to https by wildcard certificate?

Tags: https, certificate, iis7

I am using sp2013 standard edition. I have 1 frontend server and 1 sql server. I have buyed a wildcard certificate. I have googled around to find out how to install this certificate and change http to https. But I see only websites where they are talking about self signed certificates. I would like to know how it works if I have an original buyed wildcard certificate. Can someone tell me what I need to do?

I already go to IIS7 and go to "Server Certificates". I imported the certificate and stored in "Personal" and entered the password.

After this I selected the site in IIS and add a new binding. I selected inside this new binding "https" and selected the new imported certificate.

As last I went to Central Admin and go to the "Configure Alternate Access Mappings". I selected the webapplication right above. Here I see only 1 result and it is the "Default" with https url. I clicked on "Add internal URLs" and added the https url.The https url is working now. Do I need to do more for changing http to https?

I would like to make it possible to work only with https. Kan I configure it that it is only working on https and not http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this might not answer your question straight away, i had so much help from Thomas Balkeståhls blog where he provides some great guides touching the subject.

Beside from the the guides, don't forget to update your content sources in your search service to crawl HTTPS instead of HTTP when you are done with the configuration.

[A guide to https and Secure Sockets Layer in SharePoint 2013](http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/12/20/a-guide-to-https-and-secure-sockets-layer-in-sharepoint-2013/)

There's also a a great guide about AAM that could help you sorting it out.

[The final guide to Alternate Access Mappings](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/The-final-guide-to-551bd75b)

Comment: I checked the content sources. I see the https url is added automaticly:)

Comment: One reason to love SharePoint even more. :) Did it change the user profile url as well? (sp3 to sp4) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can enforce HTTPS which is good.  You have a few options:

1. Redirect HTTP to HTTPS on a load balancer if using one.
2. Check the Enforce SSL option in IIS on your web front ends.
3. Configure AAMs to redirect HTTP to HTTPS on the SharePoint application level.

AAMs seems to be the most discussed one, but if you have a large farm the first option might be more ideal to take some of the load off the actual front-ends.  But for most part, all of these options will work and you can change these in the future at any time if necessary.